# Prevent fragment from recreating

Tags: android, fragment, bottomnavigationview

I'm using the code below to show my fragment when buttons on bottom nav-bar pressed. But after a while, the RAM gets full and the app crashes out.
Here's the code:

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, new startworkLayout()).addToBackStack("TAG").commit();
```

Thank you all for helping out!

Comment: post your complete code

Comment: Do you ever pop those entries from the backstack?